# mysql want column names which are not null and not blank for given id

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Mysql i am trying to get column names for given table which values are not null and not blank for the given id values

1. I want to pass particular columns names and it needs to check which column has value not null and not blank for the given id record. it should return column names only. i have tried below query but it gives me error

> select column_name nonnull_column
> from information_schema.columns
> where table_schema = 'dbname'
> and   table_name = 'tablename'
> and   is_nullable = 'NO'
> and   tablename.id = "1";

error is Unknown column 'tablename.id' in 'where clause'

see following is my column for example
colA
colB
colC
colD
colE
colF

above are particular columns i want to check that which are not null and not blank for particular given record id need to return as column names.

for ex. if colA,colC,colD is not null for id = 5 then it should return result as

```
Columns
colA
colC
colD
```

can you help me to achieve my expected result please. Thanks

Comment: A (VERY) quick look at information_schema.columns shows there is no such column - what made you think there is and what are you trying to do

Comment: @P.Salmon what is solution for my query ?

Comment: Build a prepared statement and submit to dynamic sql see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html

Comment: @P.Salmon sorry i am not that much aware about prepared statement. can you help me to build query ?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling tablename.id but there is no reference to tablename in your `WHERE` clause anywhere.

Also, you are calling columns from `information_schema.columns` table where `tablename.id` apparently does not exist.

Comment: can you send me modified query. i do not understood your answer.

Comment: This query should do it.
```SQL
select schema_name.tablename.id, column_name nonnull_column from information_schema.columns, schema_name.tablename where table_schema = 'schema_name and table_name = 'table_name' and is_nullable = 'NO' and schema_name.table_name.id_column_name = 1;```

Comment: great let me a try .

Comment: i tried above query but it gives me error that Unknown column schema_name.tablename.id in 'field list'

Comment: @CodeEmbassy `schema_name = "Your database name"`, `table_name = "Your table name"`  and `column_name = "Your ID column name against which you are comparing"`. They are substitute names. You need to replace them with your own database and table names.

Comment: ok great i think it returns record now but why it is returning many records i am providing particular one id so it needs to return one record only but it gives me 104 result.

Comment: @CodeEmbassy Because it is returning result in Cartesian Join. You need to Inner join the value of both tables to limit them.

Comment: we have only one table so we do not have join. can you please modify the query and send me pls ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229559/discussion-between-fawad-shah-and-code-embassy).